# how to enable cors on this node server

Tags: node.js, fonts, cors

Learning Node I am looking for advice on where to put the CORS declarations for my server. 
I have a website running on https://example.com and a node server running on https://example.com:4343.

The goal is to use the css, and the fonts from the site on the node app. For Css non problems with cors. For fonts CORS is blocking downloading

Actual code is the following:

```
const https = require("https"),
  fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/***/privkey.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/***/fullchain.pem")
};

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
// Copy the .env.example in the root into a .env file in this folder

const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

app.use(express.static(process.env.STATIC_DIR));
app.use(
  express.json({
    // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
    // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
    verify: function(req, res, buf) {
      if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("/webhook")) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    }
  })
);
```

I know I have to put something like this:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
```

to enable fonts from my domain in my node server that is running on example.com:4343
but where and how to put it? Or do I need something different?

The actual headers for my request are:

```
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: application/font-woff2;q=1.0,application/font-woff;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: identity
Origin: https://example.com:4343
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 14:19:09 GMT
If-None-Match: "466c-5a482bf8bff8e"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

and on Firefox looks it is correctly load (200 or 304 when cache is used) but the dev tools say it is blocked by CORS

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From what I understand you have fonts saved on you example.com website and you want to use them in your Node based example.com:4343 website.

Allowing CORS depends which software is serving your https://example.com website.

You should allow CORS not in the Node application that runs example.com:4343, but in the webserver that serves example.com.

If the web server is Apache, then [add this line in the `.htaccess` file](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).

[This](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) is how you set it up if you use NGINX.

If the example.com webserver is using Node, I suggest you to use the `cors` middleware for express:

- `npm install cors`

  ```js
  const express = require('express')
  const cors = require('cors')
  const app = express()

  app.use(cors())
  ```

as described in the [following guide](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: the webserver is apache. So you say I should enable CORS on APACHE from domain.com:4343?

Comment: No, if the fonts you need are stored in `domain.com`, then you should enable CORS for that domain changing the `.htaccess` file inside the root folder of the `domain.com` site.

If instead you need fonts that are under `domain.com:4343`, then you should change the Node app adding `cors` support to Express. I suggest doing that as explained in the answer.

Comment: i am requesting from domain.com:4343 fonts that are in domain.com. So in my vhost I enabled CORS for domain.com:4343 (no way I'll put *) but nothing changed

Comment: Note that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com:4343` is NOT equivalent to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com:4343` and is NOT equivalent to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com:4343`